# Reference request: sequence of Gaussians in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, gaussian-measure

I am familiar with basic probability and measure theory, and would like to know if there is an easily accessible reference, where I can understand under what conditions something like the following makes sense:
$$
w = (w_1, \dots, w_n, \dots) \sim N_\infty(0, \Sigma),
$$
is an infinite dimensional sequence of Gaussians, and $\Sigma$ is a positive, self-adjoint operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. I would like to understand things like when $\mathbb{E}[\langle w, A w\rangle_{\ell^2(\mathbb{N})}]$ is meaningful, exists and is finite, when $A$ is a positive operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Is there a relatively accessible resource for this type of thing?

Comment: I don't know anything along this line, but we have to be very careful about $\Sigma$. For example if $\Sigma$ is the identity operator, we are saying that $w_i$'s are i.i.d standard Gausian variable, then $w$ is almost surely not in $\mathcal l^2(\mathbb N)$, because the probability $w_n\rightarrow 0$ is $0$.

Comment: Although one can imagine that if $\Sigma$ is trace class and has vanishing eigenvalues, probably this is OK?

Comment: Also, how should we interpret something like $\langle w, A w\rangle$, when $A \colon l^2(\mathbb{N}) \to l^2(\mathbb{N})$, and $w$ is a sequence of iid standard $N(0, 1)$ variables. Even though $w$ is not in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, it seems $\sqrt{A}w$ could be, and so there could be meaning to this expression?

Comment: Yeah, I guess trace class is a good condition. This is interesting. We often have to consider unbounded operators whose domain is not the whole space. Now we are considering "unbounded" vectors while the operator can behave well.